# Script with querySelector works only once for class

Tags: javascript

The script below works fine for the first div with the `.inp` class, it doesn't work for the second block with the same class. I broke my head trying to figure out why this is happening and how to make it work, while NOT ADDING new classes or IDs to the second div.

```js
document.querySelector("input").focus();

document.querySelector(".inp").addEventListener("input", function({ target, data }){
  // Exclude non-numeric characters (if a value has been entered)
  data && ( target.value = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') );
  
  const hasValue = target.value !== "";
  const hasSibling = target.nextElementSibling;
  const hasSiblingInput = hasSibling && target.nextElementSibling.nodeName === "INPUT";

  if ( hasValue && hasSiblingInput ){

    target.nextElementSibling.focus();
  
  } 
});
```

```css
.inp input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>
```

Comment: The `.querySelector()` function only returns the first matching element. If you want more than one, use `.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a list of elements.

Comment: I also noticed that you do not have any iteration logic here either, which will be required once you start playing with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
document.querySelector("input").focus();

document.querySelectorAll(".inp").forEach(inp => {
  inp.addEventListener("input", function({ target, data }){
  // Exclude non-numeric characters (if a value has been entered)
  data && ( target.value = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') );
  
  const hasValue = target.value !== "";
  const hasSibling = target.nextElementSibling;
  const hasSiblingInput = hasSibling && target.nextElementSibling.nodeName === "INPUT";

  if ( hasValue && hasSiblingInput ){

    target.nextElementSibling.focus();
  
  } 
 });
})
```

```css
.inp input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>
```

As Pointy mentioned querySelector() method can only be used to access a single element while querySelectorAll() method can be used to access all elements which match with a specified CSS selector.

Comment: Now figured it out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using `(document|element).querySelector` will give the first element which matches the query.

You can user `(document|element).querySelectorAll` instead in this scenario.

```js
document.querySelector("input").focus();

document.querySelectorAll(".inp").forEach(element=>element.addEventListener("input", function({ target, data }){
  // Exclude non-numeric characters (if a value has been entered)
  data && ( target.value = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') );
  
  const hasValue = target.value !== "";
  const hasSibling = target.nextElementSibling;
  const hasSiblingInput = hasSibling && target.nextElementSibling.nodeName === "INPUT";

  if ( hasValue && hasSiblingInput ){

    target.nextElementSibling.focus();
  
  } 
}))
```

```css
.inp input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>

<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" name="digit1" />
  <input type="text" name="digit2" />
  <input type="text" name="digit3" />
  <input type="text" name="digit4" />  
  <input type="text" name="digit5" />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.querySelector` will work only for the first element it finds, you should use `.querySelectorAll` instead. It will return a node list of all selectors with your class.

Then you can iterate with a loop through all of them and add the event listener.